# Dropzone.js acceptedFiles not working with drag&drop

Tags: dropzone.js

I have set Dropzone to accept only this files:

```
acceptedFiles:
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/msword",
```

also tried in this other two ways:

```
acceptedFiles: ".docx, .doc",

acceptedFiles:
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/msword, .docx, .doc",
```

but isn't working with drag&drop. It's working only with the "clickable" option, so the fileInput is doing his job.

The function getAcceptedFiles() returns an empty array `[]`. It is only the visual impact that shows the dropped files. Am I missing something? I have to manually exclude them from the preview?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: The default implementation of accept checks the file's mime type or extension against this list. This is a comma separated list of mime types or file extensions.
Eg.: image/*,application/pdf,.psd
If the Dropzone is clickable this option will also be used as [accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept) parameter on the hidden file input as well.

You can see example: 

https://jsfiddle.net/sivard/yb44p12m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there isn't a default implementation for this. You must implement the logic for the drag&drop.

```
    const maxFilesNumber = 1;
    //after complete adding files, remove if not accepted or maxFilesNumber reached
        dropzone.on("complete", (file) => {
          if (!file.accepted || dropzone.files.length > maxFilesNumber)
            dropzone.removeFile(file);
        });
    
    dropzone.on("maxfilesreached", () => dropzone.disable() );
    
    //reset event is fired when files in dropzone are 0
    dropzone.on("reset", () => dropzone.enable() );
```